# Можно ли обратиться к полю объекта не суперкласса, а суперкласса у супекласса?

Tags: java, наследование, syntax

Можно ли обратиться к полю объекта не суперкласса, а суперкласса у супекласса, не создавая дополнительных объектов (только один объект крайнего подкласса)?

```
   //Суперкласс (отдельный java файл):
    public class Solution {
        int age = 1;
    }

    //Подкласс (отдельный java файл):
    public class Cat extends Solution {
        int age = 2;
    }

    //Подкласс у подкласса (отдельный java файл):
    public class Cat2 extends Cat {
        int age = 3;
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Cat2 cat = new Cat2();
            cat.m1();
        }

        public void m1() {
            System.out.println(super.super.age); //Что писать здесь, что бы вывелось 1?
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Cat0 {
    int age = 1;
    protected int getAge_Cat0(){ return age; }
}

public class Cat1 extends Cat0 {
    int age = 2;
    protected int getAge_Cat1(){ return age; }
}

public class Cat2 extends Cat1 {
    int age = 3;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat2 cat = new Cat2();
        cat.m1();
    }

    public void m1() {
        System.out.println(getAge_Cat0()); 
    }   
}
```

или

```
public class Cat0 {
    protected int age = 1;
}

public class Cat1 extends Cat0 {
    protected int age = 2;
}

public class Cat2 extends Cat1 {
    int age = 3;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat2 cat = new Cat2();
        cat.m1();
    }

    public void m1() {
        System.out.println( ((Cat0)this).age ); 
    }   
}
```